# Sub domain index.php file conflict with main domain

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter, subdomain

My subdomain for e.g http://web.example.com/ and main domain http://example.com/
My site hosted on gandi.net server, When i have created sub domain it's automatically created subdomain folder `web.example.com`

Folder structure is:

Main domain: `/lamp0/web/vhosts/example.com/htdocs/` and source code of wp

Sub domain: `/lamp0/web/vhosts/web.example.com/htdocs/` and source code of ci

My main domain site in `WordPress` and subdomain site in `codeigniter` framework.
When i run the sub domain it's call the WordPress index.php file

Wordpress .htaccess is:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

And codeigniter .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Anyone can suggest me where is the issue ? why calling the main domain file when i try to subdomain.

Comment: Why don't you try the gandi.net help pages [here](https://wiki.gandi.net/en/dns/zone/subdomain?s[]=subdomain)?

Comment: I already get help with support team, but they say coding issue.@ShutUpMagda

Comment: Are you controlling the web server? Can you get access to the server's config files?

Comment: Yes both site file i can controlling via sFTP @ShutUpMagda

Comment: So create a subdomain by hand. It is not enough to changing directory names like you did. You need to tell to your webserver that a different configuration to this directory exists. Then, you'll need to set your DNS rules to match with your webserver settings. **OBS:** `.htaccess` files control the directory rules, not the 'server configuration'. What is your server (Apache, nigx, etc)?

Comment: thanks for your information @ShutUpMagda . Server linux.

Comment: Linux, ok, but what's your webserver [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/), [nginx](https://www.nginx.com/), etc?

Comment: If it's calling the Wordpress index.php then it looks like a DNS configuration or a server configuration problem. I doubt code (or .htaccess) have anything to do with this. To make sure, create a test.html file in your subdomain only with a simple frase or word. Then try your browser `web.example.com/test.html`, if you get a Wordpress 404 error then it is not a coding error.

Comment: Man, gandi.net has a control panel where you can do such configuration settings.

Comment: webserver appache @ShutUpMagda and sub domain creating on simple hosting where gandi.net provide

Comment: @MarcCompte yes when i try to test.html or test.php it's work!!! , but when i run only web.example.com it's direct calling wordpress index file and when try rename of wp file index1.php that time run the sub domain perfect, and then wp site not work.

Comment: @ShutUpMagda does not provide cPanel, file management using sftp only

Comment: Then [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/463623), or [this](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/examples.html), or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18342313/6054930) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13838733/6054930) should help you.