# How to setup a subdomain in a site's server?

Tags: html, linux, webserver

I have a domain name , hacks4liveprojects.com , but I want to make a subdomain; somethinghere.hacks4liveprojects.com or something like that. My site is hosted on an Ubuntu 17.10 Server.

How to do this?

My site is in : /var/www/html/ if you wanted to know...

Edit :  grammar

Comment: Already someone has given answer follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18342208/setting-up-a-subdomain-with-apache-on-linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Make a directory in your /var/www/html named somethinghere
- Go to /etc/apache2/sites-available
- Copy the 000-default.conf to somethinghere.conf
- edit somethinghere.conf
- change the ServerName to **somethinghere.hacks4liveprojects.com** and Directory /var/www/html to **Directory /var/www/html/somethinghere**. The same goes for DocumentRoot
- Then activate it with **sudo a2ensite somethinghere.conf** and reload your apache settings with **sudo service apache2 reload**

Comment: Deze site is niet bereikbaar
Het IP-adres van de server van cydia.hacks4liveprojects.com kan niet worden gevonden.
Zoek op Google naar cydia
ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: That sounds like you need to add a subdomain at your DNS hoster. There you need to put your IP address of your webserver